# DotNetZip How Add Selected Files without creating folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetzip

I want to add in zip file `"test"` all pdf files from `path`

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.AddSelectedFiles("*.pdf",path);
                    zip.Save(path+"/test.zip"); 
                }
```

when test.zip file is created have this  directory :

```
**test.zip**\Users\administrator\Documents\vs2010\Projects\my project\**pdf files**
```

How to make all pdf documents to be directly in test.zip

```
 test.zip\pdf files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following,

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    // filter the files for *.pdf
    zip.AddFiles(files, "Test"); //Test Folder 
    zip.Save(path+"/test.zip"); 
  }
```